# Find correct to 6 decimal places, the x-coordinate of the point on the curve y = ln x which is closest to the origin.

Tags: newton-raphson

I must use the Newton Raphson method.

Can someone please explain the steps I must take in order to reach the answer. For alot of this im having to self study the material to catch up and without instruction, im quite lost on how to approach the problem. I wasnt given any initial values, so am i to assume that i must use the distance formula or..

Comment: So let's take some value for $x$, let's say $x=t$. On the graph, this corresponds to the point $(t,\ln t)$. What is the distance of this point from the origin?

Comment: so using the distance formula id get d=sqrt(x^2 + (lnx)^2. but do i now use this as the f(x) function nd then divide it by its derivative? so that i can find x1 x2 and so forth using newton raphson

Comment: Let's not worry about any iterative methods yet. We don't even know what we're trying to solve yet. So we have the function for the distance, which is
$$
d(t) = \sqrt{t^2 + \ln^2 x}
$$
The graph of this function looks like this: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9w4dpwyhsp

So now what we're interested in is the **minimum** of this function. As you can see form the graph, there is one quite clear minimum point. Do you know how to find the minimum of a function? Hint: The value that minimises $\sqrt{g(x)}$ is the same as for $g(x)$, without the square root.

Comment: to find mins and maximums i must find the critical values right, using the derivative nd second order derivative right?

Comment: Yes so what you have to know is that if a (continous and smooth) function has a minimum, then the **derivative of that function is zero** at that point. So with this in mind, in order to find the minimum value of $d(t)$, we have to find the **derivative** of $d(t)$ first. But we can make the problem significantly easier by getting rid of the square root. So now we're interested in the derivative of 
$$
f(t) = d^2 (t) = t^2 + \ln^2 t
$$
Can you calculate the derivative?

Comment: its gonna be 2t+2ln(t)/t

Comment: again im really sorry, i feel like im being daft or like slow, please bare with me:)

Comment: Yes you are correct. So now we are interested in finding the values of $t$ that are the solutions to the equation
$$
h(t) = f'(t) = \frac{2t^2 + 2\ln t}{t} = 0
$$
(just a slight re-write of the derivative). Now we have an actual equation to solve and we can use numerical methods. Do you know how to proceed?

Comment: It's all good - most people don't even reply to efforts in helping them!

Comment: id put the original f(t) function (essentially the distance formula) nd divide it by f'(t) nd ultimately subtract this whole value from tn, or must i still ignore the iterative method

Comment: Forget about everything else and let's just focus on this:
$$
h(t) = \frac{2t^2 + 2 \ln t}{t} = 0
$$
This is the equation that needs an iterative, numerical solution.

Comment: ok, so if i need to find the o's of this funtion i must just find the critical values. so essentially when t = 0 and when the numerator is equal to 0

Comment: The critical value is the solution to the equation that I wrote. So now we only want to solve the equation numerically. The graph of $h(x)$ looks like this: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vbiofbx8bx

See how it has a pretty clear, single root? That's what we want to find numerically.

Comment: Actually, I see another point that we can use to make the equation easier: When we want to solve
$$
\frac{2t^2 + 2 \ln t}{t} = 0
$$,
it suffices that $2t^2 + 2 \ln t = 0$ .

Comment: I know that there are a lot of equations and functions, but the way to the correct solution is just to advance logically in each step ...

Comment: 2lnt = -2t^2,,,,,,,,, which can be -2t^2/2 = lnt,,,,,,,,,,so e^(ln t) = e^-2t^2/2,,,,,,,, t = e^-t^2

Comment: Yes, good that you have looked for algebraic solutions - and noticed that there are none. So now we only have the equation
$$
2t^2 + 2\ln t = 0
$$
to solve. Forget everything else than this equation. Time to take out the Newton-Rhapson method.

Comment: what would i use for the xn value tho

Comment: What do you refer to, by $x_n$ ? The way the method works is that you pick a starting value for the unknown variable (in this case, $t$ - and in many cases it doesn't matter at all which value you choose) and then you calculate an improved value based on that initial guess. If I were you, I would choose $t_0 = 1$ as the initial guess.

Comment: ohhh, so i can pick the intial value for t. coz isnt the formula xn-f(xn)/f'(xn). either way that makes things alot clearer

Comment: x(n+1) = 1 - (2(1)^2+ 2 ln(1))/4(1) + 2/1)

Comment: Looks good, go on. After the first iteration, you really need a calculator because the values will not be rational numbers.

Comment: so 1- (2/6),,,,,, 1-(1/3),,,,,, x(n+1) = 2/3

Comment: since we got x1 , i now keep finding iterations right?

Comment: Yes, essentially the process is infinite and it gets more and more accurate each time.

Comment: 2/3 - (2(2/3)^2+ 2ln(2/3)/4(2/3) + 2/2/3)

Comment: i know this is prob dumb, but id know to stop when the values start moving awy from the orgin again right?

Comment: I get the following iteration values:
$$
t_0 = 1
$$
$$
t_1 = \frac{2}{3}
$$
$$
t_2 \approx 0.652~909
$$

Comment: What do you mean "moving away from the origin"? Which origin? In this case, if you have calculated everything correctly, the iteration should **converge** - and quite quickly, too.

Comment: oh i get it now, thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

The closest point of the curve has an $x$-coordinate that is the solution of the equation
$$f(x)=x^2+\log x =0$$
as $f\left(\frac12\right)=\frac14-\log 2<0$ and $f(1)=1>0$, for the intermediate values theorem the root is in the interval $(0.5,1)$

So we take $x_0=0.5$ and $x_n=x_{n-1}-\frac{f(x_{n-1})}{f'(x_{n-1})}$

$$
\begin{array}{l|r|r}
 n & x_n & error\\
\hline
 0 & 0.5 &\\
 1 & 0.647716 & 0.147716 \\
 2 & 0.652917 & 0.00520115 \\
 3 & 0.652919 & 1.77\times 10^{-6} \\
 4 & 0.6529186404 & 1.9\times 10^{-13} \\
\end{array}
$$

The solution with $6$ exact decimal places is $x^*=0.652919$